# Use the same `before_action` filter in multiple controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails app, I have a `before_action` filter that sends a webhook message. Since I have a few controllers that I want the `before_action` to act on, is there a good way to make it a module and prepend it?

My current logic is:

```
# first_controller.rb:
before_action :do_something
def do_something
 #same logic
end

# second_controller.rb:
before_action :do_something
def do_something
 #same logic
end

# third_controller.rb:
before_action :do_something
def do_something
 #same logic
end
```

Answer (score 7):

If your controllers inherit from ApplicationController, You can do the following:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def do_something
   #same logic
  end
end

class FirstController < ApplicationController
  before_action :do_something
end
class SecondController < ApplicationController
  before_action :do_something
end
class ThirdController < ApplicationController
  before_action :do_something
end
```

Or you can make your own parent controller, eg. DoSomethingController

```
class DoSomethingController < ApplicationController
  before_action do_something

  def do_something
   #same logic
  end
end

class FirstController < DoSomethingController
end
class SecondController < DoSomethingController
end
class ThirdController < DoSomethingController
end
```

Or you can use @code_aks's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59846330/8554172 to make a module and include it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is good to use DRY here. If your controllers do have same parent class you can place that method in there. If not it is good practice to move this method to the module and include it with reusing.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code write the methods in a controller concern. For example:

```
# app/controllers/concerns/example_concern.rb
module ExampleConcern
 extend ActiveSupport::Concern

 protected
 def before_filter_1
   puts "from first before_filter_method"
 end

 def before_filter_2
   puts "from second before_filter_method"
 end
end
```

Now in the controller, include the module in the concern and call the methods using before_action as required. For example:

```
# app/controllers/examples_controller.rb
class ExamplesController < ApplicationController
  include ExampleConcern

  before_action :before_filter_1, only: [:action_a, :action_b, :action_c]
  before_action :before_filter_2, only: [:action_d, :action_e]

  def action_a
  end
  def action_b
  end
  def action_c
  end
  def action_d
  end
  def action_e
  end
end
```

Hope this will help you. :)